# $jquery.post() PHP and Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, .post

So I half got jQuery's ajax (`$.post`) to work. But, for some reason, I haven't been successful with finding the right online article to explain to me how PHP retrieves the ajax data that is sent. I've found some stuff on json_decode, but upon me doing that to basically decode it, it wont work (and yes, I am using json for the `$.post` command).

Here is my javascript code

```
$.post("notificationNum.php", {"user":"1"},
                function(data){
                        $(".example-number").html(data.amount);
                }, "json");
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
session_start();
//link to db info here

$user_id_got = json_decode($_REQUEST['user']);

$checknoti = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_users = '".$user_id_got."' AND notification_viewed= '0'");

  echo json_encode(array("amount"=>mysql_num_rows($checknoti)));
?>
```

Mind you all, I've also tried using the `$_POST` command instead of the `$_REQUEST`. Any ideas how to send data to the PHP file so I can use it?

Comment: Try `print_r( $_POST )`.

Comment: Is `notificationNum.php` getting called in the first place?  Can you do something like a `var_dump` to see the contents of `$_REQUEST`?  Maybe try using a tool like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what data is flowing back and forth to the server.

Comment: notificationNum.php is getting called, I already did something to make sure it is being called, and it works. Just getting the information is the problem and retrieving it in PHP.

Comment: Your code is assuming that the jquery is actually sending over a JSON string. You're not, you're just constructing a regular POST system, so passing that data through json_decode in PHP will return null (check json_last_error() to confirm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"json" in your jQuery call is how your php should *write* its output, not how jQuery sends it. Use normal $_REQUEST in your php:

```
 $user_id_got = $_REQUEST['user'];
```

Comment: Actually, wait, this did work, but there was a problem with my code. However, is there a way to get a session in php and pass it through jQuery's ajax call?

Comment: I have a $_SESSION[''] in place in the very same file the $.post is being executed. Can I send the information in the $_SESSION through $.post? Such as.... $.post("notificationNum.php", {"user":<?php $_SESSION['here']; ?>},
                function(data){
                        $(".example-number").html(data.amount);
                }, "json");

Comment: @Majed: The session is on the server already, why would you need to pass it from the client to the server??

Comment: Because, notificationNum.php is not accessing it for some reason, so instead, I need to pass it to the file.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the help, you gave me the right answer, thus you will be rewarded for that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

#### notificationNum.php

```
<?php
//link to db info here

$user_id_got = intval($_POST['user']);

$checknoti = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_users = '".$user_id_got."' AND notification_viewed= '0'");

echo json_encode(array("amount"=>mysql_num_rows($checknoti)));
?>
```